# How to perform drag and drop on dynamically rendering Angular js application using protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to perform drag n drop of  using protractor 7.0.0 and node v12.18.2 but unable to do so. I tried it with both chrome and firefox. In chrome, test case is being passed but no drag and drop action is being performed at GUI level. In firefox, receiving "HTTP method not allowed" error message.
The mouse-click icon is appearing but unable to perform drag n drop.
Code is:

```
    it("Drag and Drop", async function() {
            //await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
            var source_elem = element(by.cssContainingText('li > a > figure > label', 'HDFS')).element(by.xpath('../../..'));
            const target = $('#main');
            source_elem.click();
            browser.actions().dragAndDrop(source_elem, target).perform();
});
```

Error received in firefox:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQctv.png)

Comment: you need to handle promises

Comment: I am new to this so don't have much idea. Can you suggest where can I refer for this ? @SergeyPleshakov